# 'npm start' command failed in MarkLogic grove

Tags: node.js, npm, marklogic

I'm trying to install MarkLogic Glove according to following documentation.

[Quick Creation of a new Grove project](https://marklogic-community.github.io/grove/guides/getting-started/)

But the 'npm start' command to start the Grove Project failed.
The procedure I actually executed are following

1) Install the grove-cli

```
# npm install -g @marklogic-community/grove-cli

/usr/bin/grove -> /usr/lib/node_modules/@marklogic-community/grove-cli/index.js
 + @marklogic-community/grove-cli@1.0.1
 added 79 packages from 60 contributors in 8.768s
```

2) Generate a new project

```
# mkdir -p /var/opt/groveprj
# cd /var/opt/groveprj
# grove new testprj01
? Please confirm the name of your new project testprj01
? Do you want to create your Grove project with the React or the Vue UI? React


Congratulations, you successfully generated a new Grove project.
:
Log into your application using any MarkLogic user with sufficient permissions.
```

3) configure project 'testprj01'

```
# cd testprj01
# grove config
? What host is your instance of MarkLogic running on? [*IP address which MarkLogic is listening*]
? What port do you want to use for your MarkLogic REST server? [*Port number which MarkLogic is listening*]
? What port do you want your Grove Node server to listen on? 9003
```

4) Provision MarkLogic

```
# cd marklogic
# ./gradlew mlDeploy

:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3m 36s
```

5) Install npm dependencies

```
# cd ..
# npm install

npm WARN lifecycle @marklogic-community/grove-react-template@1.0.0~postinstall: cannot run in wd @marklogic-community/grove-react-template@1.0.0 node scripts/postinstall.js (wd=/var/opt/groveprj/testprj01)
added 45 packages from 35 contributors and audited 51 packages in 2.432s
found 2 high severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Since the message above displayed, after I executed 'npm audit fix' and executed 'npm install' again

```
# npm audit fix

updated 1 package in 1.029s
fixed 2 of 2 vulnerabilities in 51 scanned packages

# npm install
npm WARN lifecycle @marklogic-community/grove-react-template@1.0.0~postinstall: cannot run in wd @marklogic-community/grove-react-template@1.0.0 node scripts/postinstall.js (wd=/var/opt/groveprj/testprj01)
audited 51 packages in 0.888s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

6) Start  server

```
# npm start
```

At this point, the following message is displayed and npm start failed.

```
[1]
[1] > @marklogic-community/grove-react-template@1.0.0 ui /var/opt/groveprj/testprj01
[1] > cd ui && npm start
[1]
[0]
[0] > @marklogic-community/grove-react-template@1.0.0 middleTier /var/opt/groveprj/testprj01
[0] > cd middle-tier && npm start
[0]
[1]
[1] > @marklogic-community/grove-react-ui@1.0.0 start /var/opt/groveprj/testprj01/ui
[1] > react-scripts start
[1]
[1] sh: react-scripts: command not found
[1] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[1] npm ERR! syscall spawn
[1] npm ERR! file sh
[1] npm ERR! errno ENOENT
[1] npm ERR! @marklogic-community/grove-react-ui@1.0.0 start: `react-scripts start`
[1] npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
:
```

It seems that react-scripts could not be installed properly.

The environment I use is following

OS version: CentOS 7.4
MarkLogic version: 9.0-11
Nodejs version: v13.5.0
npm version: 6.13.4
Java version: 1.8.0_231

Comment: It looks like ui dependencies did not install correctly. Could you try running npm install inside the ui directory?